# Delete Excel Chart

Tags: c#, excel, charts

I want to delete a Chart from an Excel file.
The Excel file is an automatically generated historyfile with a chart, the problem is, that every time I renew the history, it makes a new chart, but the old one must be deleted...
This is my code:

```
Excel.Workbook ExcelWorkBook = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(path);
ExcelApp.Visible = true;
Excel.Worksheet Sheet = (Excel.Worksheet)ExcelWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
Excel.Range range = Sheet.UsedRange;
int i = 2;
while (Convert.ToString((range.Cells[i, 1] as Excel.Range).Value2) != null)
{
    i++;
}

Excel.Range oRange;
Excel._Chart oChart;
Excel.Series oSeries;
oChart = (Excel._Chart)ExcelWorkBook.Charts.Add(Missing.Value, Missing.Value,
Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
oRange = Sheet.get_Range("A2:H" + i).get_Resize(Missing.Value, 8);
oChart.ChartWizard(oRange, Excel.XlChartType.xlLineStacked, Missing.Value,
Excel.XlRowCol.xlColumns, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value,"Chart01");
oSeries = (Excel.Series)oChart.SeriesCollection(1);
oSeries.XValues = Sheet.get_Range("A2", "A" + i);
oChart.Location(Excel.XlChartLocation.xlLocationAsObject, Sheet.Name);
```

Now I need to delete the existing Chart before that code.

Something like

```
Excel._Chart asdf = Sheet.ChartObjects("Chart01").Chart;
if (asdf != null)
{
    asdf.Delete();
}
```

This doesn't find a chart with name "Übersicht" but there is a chart with title "Übersicht"

EDIT:
The Problem now is that it can't delete the Chart: *Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC*

Comment: is variable Excel._Chart asdf = null?

Comment: I don't even get to that point, the code stops at `Excel._Chart asdf =... `

Comment: @jochot 1. how did you rename the Chart to `Chart01`??

Comment: Manually, i went into the Excel file and changed the Name, then automatically by the programm itself (`Excel.XlRowCol.xlColumns, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value,"Chart01");`) 

Both didn't work

Comment: Maybe its not this sheet... try Sheet.ChartObjects.Count if return more then 0 print chart name by ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Excel make sure that the Chart actually exists with the name.

You can rename a chart using

```
Sheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects(1).Name = "Chart01"
```

then when you click on the chart in the spreadsheet view you can see that it actually renamed

[image]

On the C# side I would suggest a minimal example like this

```
bool deleted = false;
try
{
    ChartObject myChart = ws.ChartObjects("Chart01");
    myChart.Delete();
    deleted = true;
}
catch
{
    MessageBox.Show("Chart with this name could not be found");
    //throw new Exception("Chart with this name could not be found");
}
finally
{
    MessageBox.Show("the chart was " + (deleted ? "deleted" : "not deleted"));
}
```

Comment: I Changed the Name of the Chart like in your picture and now it finds the chart, but it can't delete it, the Exception is _Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC_

Comment: declare your chart object as `ChartObject` not `_Chart`?

Comment: @jochot you don't need to provide solution within your question. When you accept an answer it means that this is the solution that works for you. I would leave your question as is for any future visitor who may ran into a similar, even same problem.

Comment: ok, didn't know that ;) 
Now the Problem is, that if there is no Chart in there, I get an Exception, and I can't do something like `if (Sheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1"))`, because I get an Exception here too

Comment: @jochot just wrap your code with a try/catch/finally. Not sure I can help much more here. If you still can't fix it consider asking a new question as I believe this one should now be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try to rename the chart name to plain English like: 'Chart01'.
The issue might be due to Unicode support.

Comment: _The item with the specified name wasn't found._
With "Chart01" too, ArgumentException